# How can I use fontspec to set a sans heading font with mathdesign

Tags: fontspec, mathdesign

I like the `mathdesign` package, but would like to use Myriad Pro section headings in `LuaLaTeX`.  Is this possible, or do I have to convert an OTF font to T1? (My ignorance of  font issues in *TeX is boundless.) The `\setsansfont` command and `mathdesign` packages seem not to work together, though there is no mention of fontspec within mathdesign.  Here's a MWE that shows what doesn't work when running through LuaLaTeX.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage [english] {babel}
 \usepackage {blindtext}
 \usepackage {titlesec}
 \usepackage {etoolbox}
 \usepackage {ifluatex}
 \titleformat{\section}{\Large\sffamily\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

 \ifbool{luatex} { 
   \usepackage {fontspec}
   \setsansfont [Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase] {Myriad Pro}
   \usepackage [charter] {mathdesign}
 }{\usepackage [T1] {fontenc}
   \usepackage [charter] {mathdesign}
   \renewcommand*{\sfdefault}{phv} % Adobe Helvetica 
 }

 \begin{document}
 \section {A section}
 \blindmathpaper
 \end{document}
```

The beginning of that document looks as follows (note the lack of sans serif section heading)
[image: fontspec first]

If I load the `mathdesign` package before `fontspec` I get the correct section heading font, but the `rmdefault` font switches to CM.

Interestingly, the math font remains Charter in all cases.

[image]

Comment: It's not something `fontspec` can do. You need to redefine the heading commands and letting the redefined commands set the headings in sans serif with `fontspec`. To redefine the headers you can use a package but it may depend on which headers you want to redefine.

Comment: How about loading `\usepackage [charter] {mathdesign}` before `fontspec` in your preamble? I don't have myriad pro but it should work in other `otf` fonts.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen, I am redefining the section heading with the `\titleformat` command (from the `titlesec` package) to set them in sans serif.  At least that's what the intent is, and it works right up until (and unless) I use fontspec and mathdesign together.

Comment: @GTK In that case the order in which you load `titlesec` and `mathdesign` may matter but more likely, the place where you redefine the `\titlesec` command. Have you tried redefining it in the body an `\AtBeginDocument{}` command.

Comment: @hpesoj626, it makes no difference.  You can try it with any of your system fonts (say, Arial) instead of Myriad Pro

Comment: It does in mine. `\ifbool{luatex} {usepackage [charter] {mathdesign}\usepackage {fontspec}\setsansfont [Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase] {Liberation Sans} }{\usepackage [T1] {fontenc} \usepackage [charter] {mathdesign}
%   \renewcommand*{\sfdefault}{phv} % Adobe Helvetica 
 }`

Comment: @MarcvanDongen, yes, I tried that too.  I kind of exhausted myself with ordering permutations, because I was convinced that it was just my own ignorance

Comment: @hpesoj626: that gives the correct heading font, but the body is no longer charter (It's the default CM in mine)

Comment: When I compile your source I get sans seriffed titles. The `fonstspec` package also lets you redefine the default sans seriffed typeface.

Comment: you can get the Charter ITC as TrueType from http://www.font-zone.com/download.php?fid=953. Then you can  define the font with `\setmainfont` as usual

Comment: @marc, now I'm stumped.  When I compile mine with pdflatex I get sans serif title, but when I compile with lualatex I get serif titles.  When I switch the order of the `fontspec` and `mathdesign` package loading, I get sans fonts in lualatex, but the rmfamily is no longer charter (it's CM).

I created the MWE to show what didn't work for me in specifically in LuaLaTeX but worked with pdflatex.

Comment: @GTK It's another example that shows that using different LaTeX engines may cause problems. This is _exactly_ the reason why I always recommend to my students they should use one and only one engine. I always recommend they should use pdflatex (no offence to implementors of other engines).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set also the correct font encoding in order to choose the correct font (for the LuaLaTeX version):

```
\titleformat{\section}
  {\fontencoding{EU2}\Large\sffamily\bfseries}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{ifluatex}

\ifluatex
  \usepackage {fontspec}
  \setsansfont [Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase] {Myriad Pro}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
  \titleformat{\section}
    {\fontencoding{EU2}\Large\sffamily\bfseries}
    {\thesection}
    {1em}
    {}
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
  \renewcommand*{\sfdefault}{phv} % Adobe Helvetica
  \titleformat{\section}
    {\Large\sffamily\bfseries}
    {\thesection}
    {1em}
    {}
\fi

\begin{document}

\section {A section}
\blindmathpaper
\end{document}
```

Just for completeness, here is a LuaTeX only version with the fonts Herbert pointed at in a comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,
             BoldFont={CharterITC Bold BT},
             BoldItalicFont={CharterITC Bold Italic BT},
            ]{CharterITC BT}
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase]{Myriad Pro}

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\sffamily\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Abc}

\section {A section}
\blindmathpaper
\end{document}
```

Your way to specify the fonts may need to be different (here I put the fonts in the system fonts). Notice that one has to specify by hand the bold and bold italic versions, because the defaults are "Black", which `fontspec` doesn't understand. I added a boldface word just as an example.

[image]