# Combine "traditional" font packages (e.g. Type 1) with fontspec

Tags: packages, luatex, fontspec

I was having problems trying to combine a "traditional" font package (`berasans`) with fontspec (using TeX Gyre Pagella). Just using both correctly changed the text font to TeX Gyre Pagella, but text set with `\sffamily` used Latin Modern (Sans or Roman, depending on the order in which the packages were loaded) instead of Bera Sans.

Looking for a solution, I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86503/51235) suggesting (albeit in a different context) that the font encoding had to be manually set. This left me with the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\usepackage{berasans}
\let\sffamilyold\sffamily
\def\sffamily{\fontencoding{T1}\sffamilyold}

\begin{document}
TeX Gyre Pagella

\sffamily Bera Sans
\end{document}
```

which works, but I'm feeling slighly uneasy redefining `\sffamily` like that. Is there an easier/better solution for such a combination of Type 1 fonts and `fontspec`? Or even better, is there a good sans-serif OTF/TTF font to use with TeX Gyre Pagella?

Comment: According to http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/berasans/, “Bera Sans is a version of Bitstream Vera Sans slightly enhanced for use with TeX.” And the DejaVu family is based on Vera. DejaVu Sans should meet your needs.

Comment: I don't see the method you are using suggested in the answer/comments to the question you linked to. And I am not sure that defining it with `\def` is a great idea. The original is defined as a robust command. You are certainly losing some of the protections built into that command because you've declared an encoding switch before those checks are completed.

Comment: Don't change the encoding in `\sffamily`  it will not go back when you change family back with `\rmfamily` also hyphenation of words within the changed encoding area is likely to be wrong.

Comment: While you can use a type1 and T1-encoded font with xelatex I wouldn't recommend it. You will get problems with non-ascii-chars, and copy and paste could break. It is much better to look for a sensible open type version of the font you want to use.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Was right not to be at all sure about that....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see. I had only tested using my version of `\sffamily` inside groups (as in `{\sffamily sans test} serif test`), but when I do the same without groups, using `\rmfamily` to switch back, I do indeed get Latin Modern instead of the desired Pagella (due to the font encoding, as you said). So I definitely won't redefine `\sffamily`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you use the opentype version, developed  by [Arkandis Digital Foundry](http://arkandis.tuxfamily.org/openfonts.html) under the name of `Verana Sans`, or even a font inspired by Bitstream Vera, `Switzera`. Here is a demo:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\usepackage{berasans}
\let\sffamilyold\sffamily
\def\sffamily{\fontencoding{T1}\sffamilyold}
%\setsansfont{Verana Sans}
%\setsansfont{Switzera ADF}

\begin{document}
TeX Gyre Pagella

\sffamily Bera Sans

\fontspec{Verana Sans}Verana Sans. Baffling, isn’t it?

\fontspec{Switzera ADF}
Switzera ADF

\end{document}
```

[image]